# How to Install ADT and CDT plugins for Eclipse Neon in offline mode

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have installed Eclipse Neon Release (4.6.0) and I have some problems with online downloading for ADT and CDT.
Is there any way to add these plugins in an offline manner?

**Online Problem:**

In Help -> Install New Software...->Add (Name: ADT Plugin, Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

Error: Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ is not a valid repository location.

Comment: did use that same url and didn't have any problem installing the adt

Comment: Unfortunately we are sanctioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

**First**, download ADT from [ADT_Link](https://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/ADT/) and CDT from [CDT_Link](https://eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php),

**Second**, In Eclipse go to the `Help` -> `install new software...` -> `Add` -> Next to the Location field click the `Archive...` -> select the ADT.zip file,

**Third**, Do as the second step and select CDT.zip file